# Distributed Java best method for client callback method

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, jax-ws, rmi, distributed-computing

Im trying to implement an Observer/Observable pattern on an EC2 instance. I have been able to create the application using RMI relatively simply. However trying to get RMI and the Amazon cloud to work has been neer impossible for client callbacks.

RMI also limits the client applications to being Java based. Hence i've been messing around with JAX-WS in order to use SOAP messages. However i havent been able to come up with a solid way to make callbacks on the client with it.

Does anyone know of a way that i would be able to program in a similar way that RMI works with client callback methods to update Observers when something on my server has been changed, using hopefully a language independent distributed method?

I would be willing to make it so that all my clients must be written in java, but i need to be able to get it working on the EC2 instance which RMI seems incapable of doing callbacks even if i open all TCP ports and use a security manager.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a messaging solution, something like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).

In this way Observable pushes a message to subscribers (Observers). Completely decoupling your clients from the implementation language/specifics of the EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks, This seems pretty similar to JMS but without beign limited to java clients. I'll give it a try later on tonigth when im free.